# Converting multiple GPX to SHP files using ModelBuilder in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I usually use the "GPX To Features" tool to import tracks from my Garmin GPS device into ArcMap. Now I have a folder which contains around 50 GPX files which I want to convert to SHP files in one go. Using the ModelBuilder I created this model:

[image]

The problem is, that I cannot connect the green "File" oval (which should contain the current file name) as an input with the "GPX To Features" tool. The only available type of connection is "Precondition". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ArcGIS 10.2.2, I was able to connect the output of the iterator with the GPX to Feature tool as shown below:

[image: Model]

The important thing to note is that I set the extension type to simply GPX, see pop-up. I also use in-line substitution to pass the gpx file name to the output shapefile.

Comment: Also, don't type "." before the extension, i.e. "gpx", not ".gpx".